# I need to compare 2 lists of dates and generate dates in between in Excel

Tags: excel

I have 2 lists of dates. I want to find the latest date from list 1 and the earliest date from list 2, and then generate all dates that fit in between them.

[image: Picture]

So I would like find a formula that will look at list 1, determine the max so 9/6/2019, and then look at list 2, find the min, so 9/13/2019, and then give me all the dates that fit between them. So 9/7,9/8, etc up to 9/12.

Answer (score 1):

In **C1** enter:

```
=MAX(A:A)+1
```

in **C2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(IF(C1+1+1>MIN(B:B),"",C1+1),"")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]